# Use two monitors on base optiplex 9020

Tags: display, vga, dell-optiplex

I have the full dell Optiplex 9020 with no additional graphics card, it has one VGA and one serial port but that is it. Is there any way to use two monitors with it using a VGA splitter or something along those lines? The monitors I have can use DVI-D and VGA. It currently only has intel integrated graphics 6400. If there is no way for dual monitors does anyone know of a cheaper graphics card with two VGA or DVI-D ports? Or HDMI as I could get an adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer can send signal through VGA port for one monitor.

You can use a splitter to mirror your monitor, however no way to show different content on them.

Comment: OK I just edited this post to add if " If there is no way for dual monitors does anyone know of a cheaper graphics card with two VGA or DVI-D ports? Or HDMI as I could get an adapter." do you know of any, emphasis on cheap.

Comment: Optiplexs are Dell's "corporate" line of PCs, so you will often find them at second hand stores along with video cards salvaged from non-working computers. When I lived in Austin (TX) Discount Electronics was a good source for second hand Dell PC stuff you can have a look at their website to help you compare to something that might be local to you.

Answer (score 0):

A VGA splitter will not solve the problem and create an extended
desktop. All it would do is to display the same image on the two monitors.

According to the
[manual](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/optiplex-9020-desktop/docs)
you might also have two 20-pin DisplayPort connectors.
If this exists for your computer, you can solve the problem by connecting
one of the monitors with a DisplayPort-to-VGA adapter.

Another solution would be to use the USB 3.0 port that is said to exist
by the same manual. You would need some device such as this one:
[USB 3.0 to HDMI-DVI-VGA Video Graphics Card Adapter for Multiple Monitors-Add HDMI and DVI-D or HDMI and VGA (Compatible for Windows 10, 8.1, 7, XP)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01I0X4OZ0).
This device is an external video card capable of running two monitors.
(I do not know this device and cannot recommend it.)

[image]